# Updated app with launcher activity changed causing crash

Tags: android

I have updated my app with change of launcher activity class. User reporting issue about their app icon and shortcut are not working. I want to know is it an OS specific Issue ???

Error they are getting "Linker not available"

Comment: Check this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, if you have changed the class name for the Activity that used to be an intent launcher, or removed it from being a launcher then peoples current shortcuts won't work.

Simplest answer is to tell them to remove the shortcut and re-add it.

Long solution is to programatically do this yourself (latest Android API's only I believe)

Comment: expanding on the @Blundell answer. Ideally, even if you're changing all the code on it, you still should keep the same class name/package of the Launcher activity. Literally just replace the code inside the java file. That way you can keep the shortcurs.

Answer (score 0):

Register the new launcher class in your manifest file.